# Flite tts demo fails to run

Tags: c++, c, flite

I have recently been trying to use the Flite text-to-speech system (2.0) in a project of mine and when I call `flite_text_to_speech()` the program exits with this message:

```
VAL: tried to access lexicon in -1 type val
```

I made a small test program based on the code provided in the Flite documentation found [here](http://www.festvox.org/flite/doc/flite_7.html):

```
/* File: test.cpp */
#include <flite.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    cst_voice *v;
    flite_init();
    v = new_voice();
    flite_text_to_speech("This is a test",v,"play");
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles cleanly with:

```
g++ -Wall -g -o flite_test test.cpp -I/usr/local/include/flite -lflite_cmu_us_kal -lflite_usenglish -lflite_cmulex -lflite -lasound -lm
```

However, when I run ./flite-test, I still get the same error:

```
VAL: tried to access lexicon in -1 type val
```

Is this a bug in Flite or am I doing something foolish here? I know that Flite 2.0 is relatively young so I'm considering using an older version but I would much rather use the latest. Does my test code work for anyone, and if so, what should I be doing differently?

Update: I just tried the this with Flite 1.4 and the same thing happens.

Answer (score 2):

I studied the `flite` utility's source and I was able to solve my issues by copying heavily from its main function in flite_main.c.